# Convert C# to VB.Net WebBrowser Event

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters, manual

I know C# and I want to convert this code into VB.NET.

```
lol.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(Form1_Navigated);
```

I used all Online Converters but didn't work.

But I want to know how convert this code manually.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code converter. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: "didn't work" - what error do you get?  Post your full VB code or use a better code converter.

Comment: You need to learn how event handlers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddHandler lol.Navigated, AddressOf Form1_Navigated
```

And then make sure there's an event 'Form1_Navigated':

```
Private Sub Form1_Navigated(sender as Object, e as WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs)
    //Do stuff
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.